# JEE unable to insert into table ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee

I'm learning dynamic web programming java with oracle db.

This is my DAO to insert data into db

```
    staffID = bean.getStaffID();
    staffName = bean.getStaffName();//untuk ambil the value
    staffAddress = bean.getStaffAddress();
    staffNoTel= bean.getStaffNoTel();
    staffEmail = bean.getStaffEmail();
    staffPos = bean.getStaffPos();
    managerID = bean.getManagerID();
    password = bean.getPassword();

    try {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("insert into staff (staffID,staffName,staffAddress,staffNoTel,staffEmail,staffPos,managerID,password)values(staff_id_seq.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,staffID);
        ps.setString(2,staffName);
        ps.setString(3,staffAddress);
        ps.setString(4,staffNoTel);
        ps.setString(5,staffEmail);
        ps.setString(6,staffPos);
        ps.setString(7,managerID);
        ps.setString(8,password);
        ps.executeUpdate();


        System.out.println("Creating user account:");
        System.out.println("Your ID is is auto generated");
        System.out.println("Your email is " + staffEmail);
        System.out.println("Your password is " + password);


    }
```

I have double check the query in sqldeveloper and it can be executed. but when in running in JEE it give me 2 error which is:

1. Log In failed: An Exception has occurred! java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
2. failed: An Exception has occurred! java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

I have try to parseInt the staffid but it kept giving me the same error.
Previously i was doing the staffid without sequence and it gave me no error.

This is how the staff table structure look like:

```html
CREATE TABLE staff(
staffid number(10),
staffname varchar2(100),
staffaddress varchar2(100),
staffnotel varchar2(20), 
staffemail varchar2(50),
staffpos varchar2(50),
managerid NUMBER(10),
password varchar2(20),

CONSTRAINT staffid_pk PRIMARY KEY(staffid),
CONSTRAINT staffname_nn CHECK (staffname IS NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT staffadd_nn CHECK (staffaddress IS NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT staffnotel_nn CHECK (staffnotel IS NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT staffemail_nn CHECK (staffemail IS NOT NULL),
CONSTRAINT staffemail_uk UNIQUE(staffemail),
CONSTRAINT managerid_fk FOREIGN KEY(managerid) REFERENCES staff(staffid)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The inserst statement has 7 placeholders for parameters (7 characters of a question mark `?`)

```
values(staff_id_seq.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")
```

while in code you are trying to assing values to 8 parameters:

```
ps.setString(1,staffID);
ps.setString(2,staffName);
ps.setString(3,staffAddress);
ps.setString(4,staffNoTel);
ps.setString(5,staffEmail);
ps.setString(6,staffPos);
ps.setString(7,managerID);
ps.setString(8,password);
```

This leads to `SQLException: Invalid column index` error for the last 8th parameter.

---

It seems to me that you are going to assing a value of `staffID` using the sequence, if yes, then change your java code in the below way in order to avoid this error:

```
// ps.setString(1,staffID);
ps.setString(1,staffName);
ps.setString(2,staffAddress);
ps.setString(3,staffNoTel);
ps.setString(4,staffEmail);
ps.setString(5,staffPos);
ps.setString(6,managerID);
ps.setString(7,password);
```

Comment: I have changed like the one you did. well the data has been inserted but it still giving the ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: If the record has been inserted, then this code works fine and this error is not coming from this piece of code, but from a different place.